# Is honesty the best policy?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

In the first 30 minutes of the game we learn that our character is a convict (though [he never done it, he only said he'd done it so they'd call of the monkey tattooist](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wy4Zqt5Mi-c)), shoot a cop in the head with his shotgun, kill a strange girl's babysitter with a hammer and whisk the girl away with a couple of farmhands. Normally this would be antisocial behavior, but zombie apocalypses tend to change the rules slightly. So far I've been replying to the NPCs' many questions with candor, but the game saying "X will remember that" seems a little ominous.

How open should I be about my many suspicious activities? I'm mainly interested in avoiding grievous bodily harm or death being visited upon my character and his pet NPCs. Are there particular facts that have disastrous consequences if revealed, or will things work out all right if I keep being honest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the design of the game is that there are no "right" or "wrong" choices, so you don't need to worry about future "disastrous consequences" that affect the outcome of the game based on a single "wrong" decision. Your choices will sometimes affect the fate of other characters, or how those characters feel about Lee, however.

Without going into spoiler territory, I'll just say that you should remember that oftentimes, all choices have upsides and downsides, and there's no "best" answer, despite what you might hope.

In the specific example you brought up:

> Being honest about Lee's past could cause other people to be suspicious about him, sure, but concealing it could be even more disastrous if the others were able to somehow find out about it, and realized Lee had been hiding that information from them.

In general:

> If you're hoping for there to be a series a choices through which everyone you like lives and nothing ever goes wrong, you're going to be disappointed. Sorely and repeatedly.

Comment: Perhaps I did set the stakes a little high, I'll just try and act in a way that doesn't result in any unnecessary deaths.

Comment: The best way to play the game is not to worry about how to "win".  This isn't a game you "win" or "lose".  Instead, try to invest in the character and play as the character.  You'll get a lot more out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. No one will care, though, except one person. Spoilers ahead.

Kenny will be all, "Why the **** didn't you tell me? I trusted you!" If you don't tell him in episode three that you're a killer. If you do tell him, he won't care. Lily will know anyway and spill the beans.

**Note:** You can't tell anyone your secrets if Carley isn't saved in the pharmacy. You get the chance to tell people once, but Lee'll lie about it any other time.